# Unable to get a settings change to drive a UI update via Delegates

Tags: swift, delegates

I've been trying for a long time now using various techniques to get a change on my settings page to fire a UI update on my main page without any success.

I've looked at several tutorials and also many articles on here and applying the same techniques just don't seem to work.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var settingsDelegate: SettingsViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        settingsDelegate.delegate = self
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Not called when i flip between views via Navbar (suggested that i use this function to setup the delegate)
        print(segue.destination)
    }


extension MainViewController: SettingsDelegate {
    //MARK: SettingsDelegate

    func onChangeAltitudeUnits(unitType: Int) {
        // 0 imperial, 1 metric
        // This NEVER gets printed..
        print("new Unit type \(unitType)")
        unitAltitude = unitType
        displayAltitudes((allLocations.last?.altitude) ?? 0)
        print("new Unit type \(unitType)")
    }

}


class SettingsViewController: UITableViewController {

    weak var delegate: SettingsDelegate?
    /*....Other Stuff...*/

    @IBAction func altitudeUnitsChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        let selectedIndex = AltitudeUnits.selectedSegmentIndex

        defaults.set(selectedIndex, forKey: "AltitudeUnits")
        delegate?.onChangeAltitudeUnits(unitType: selectedIndex)
        // This ALWAYS gets printed
        print("Alt unit changed \(AltitudeUnits.selectedSegmentIndex)")
    }
}

protocol SettingsDelegate: class {

    func onChangeSlopeUnits(unitType: Int)
    func onChangeAltitudeUnits(unitType: Int)
    func onChangeDistanceUnits(unitType: Int)
}
```

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTh3T.png)

Comment: I'm sorry to admit i have no idea how, the Tab Bar Controller was built from Storyboard and then a number of scenes added to it. From the IB properties it looks to be just a standard UITabBar no custom classes or anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var settingsDelegate: SettingsViewController?
```

... this is not reference for view controller which `delegate` you want to set. It looks like this is just `nil`.

Also overridden `prepare(for:sender:)` isn't called because you don't perform any segue when you switch between tabs

---

Since you're using tab bar controller and you want to set delegates between its embed controllers, you have to set delegate of certain view controller from tab bar controller's `viewControllers` array

```
func setDelegate() {
    guard let tabBarController = tabBarController, let thirdVC = tabBarController.viewControllers?[2] as? SettingsViewController else { return }
    thirdVC.delegate = self
}
```

then call this method in `MainViewController`'s overridden `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Thanks Robert, i've tried using that function with a simple print statement and it seems to never get called? Hence why i abandoned it assuming the Nav bar is doing something i'm unaware of under the covers

Comment: Perfect thanks, i assumed it was something to do with the way the tab bar was working so thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

## set your class refrences in prepare for segue like belowe :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       let destinationControler = segue. destination as! SettingsViewController
       destinationControler.delegate = self
}
```